# access to var from template in php before compile

Tags: php, smarty

I want in template file can limit count of result, something like this :

file.tpl

```
{$box_count = 10}

{foreach $box}
.
.
.
{/foreach}
```

how can i handle and get this variables in php to limit result in database ?

example :

```
<?php
$smarty = new Smarty;


$count = ... //HOW CAN GET ?

$data = array();
$q = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 0,$count" );
while( $r = mysql_fetch_array( $q ) )
{
    $data[] = $r;
}
$smarty->assign( 'box' , $data );

$smarty->dipslay( 'file.tpl' );
?>
```

**note** :
because this var just defined in tpl file, in `getTemplateVars()` not exists .

thanks

Comment: Can you access the DB query?

Comment: @Goikiu yes, added more detail .

Comment: How is the flow? Which page is called first?

Comment: @Goikiu only call php file, for example index.php, i want in index.php first get count in tpl file, after assign box var to smarty .

Comment: I think you can do it another way. From the template (where you have the count) you call the other .php page. Inside this page you put your code inside a function and after including it you "call" the function with the parameter you want (used for the limit query).

Comment: @Goikiu ok, can you give me code to how done this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem with `registerObject` :

```
<?php
$smarty = new Smarty;

class Test
{
    public function setCount( $params , &$smarty )
    {
        $count = $params['count'];

        $data = array();
        $q = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 0,$count" );
        while( $r = mysql_fetch_array( $q ) )
        {
            $data[] = $r;
        }
        $smarty->assign( 'box' , $data );
    }
}

$S = new Test;
$smarty->registerObject( 'Test' , $S , array( 'setCount' ) )

$smarty->dipslay( 'file.tpl' );
?>
```

file.tpl :

```
{Test->setCount count="10"}
{foreach $box}
.
.
.
{/foreach}
```